# Table Sorting/Search Using Server-Side

Tags: php, html, mysql, datatable, tablesorter

I currently have developed a web application using PHP and MySQL. The application requires a table that is sortable and searchable. Right now I use tablesorter with JS/JQuery.

Here is the issue. The table data is always growing. Right now there are well over 5000 rows to search/sort. It grows about 300 rows a week. Due to this, tablesorter has become incredibly slow and it can take a slower computer up to 5 minutes to load the page.

I am looking for a solution to this. I am not sure if the best idea is to use a server-side version of tablesorter or not, but as of now that is what I am looking for.

I have searched everywhere for a table sorter that isn't so heavy on the client side. Also FYI I use code igniter. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

There is a jquery plugin called datatables that does this and supports server-side processing https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

There is also a library for codeigniter to integrate the server-side datatable processing with activerecord - https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables

I use both of them, they work well together.

Comment: Great! I will check these out